# dynamically expose Web Services

Tags: web-services, spring, cxf, jibx

I have a pure pojo business interface and implementation with no jax-ws/spring annotations.
I want to expose these services dynamically as web services if they are configured with specific custom annotations.
Can you please suggest some thoughts and ideas which I can develop further on.

Answer (score 1):

CXF can definitely handle this.   The CXF "simple" frontend is designed for annotationless services.   You can write your own subclasses of DefaultServiceConfiguration that can pull the information needed from any source if you need specific customizations.   (The JAX-WS subclass pulls from JAX_WS annotations)

Comment: I had checked out cxf simple front end.My understanding is that it does not support complex input objects and does not work well with jaxb. Is my understanding right ?

Comment: I did not find a class DefaultServiceConfiguration in the cxf source code . Is it org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceConfiguration?